# Need help configuring SOF-ELK Sans to parse IIS W3C logs

Tags: logging, monitoring

How can I get the SOF-ELK VM to inject the IIS logs like the httpd logs. Here are my filebeats yml configs:

/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml

```
filebeat.config.inputs:
  enabled: true
  path: /usr/local/sof-elk/lib/filebeat_inputs/*.yml

filebeat.config.modules:
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml

output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

/etc/filebeat/modules.d/iis.yml

```
- module: iis
  access:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/logstash/iis"]
 
  error:
    enabled: true
    var.paths: ["/var/log/logstash_iis/"]
```

I reloaded and restarted the system, it does not injest or exist in the dropdowns:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to put those into /logstash/httpd/ as long as the IIS format is supported.  If it is not, you may need to add/adjust a grok statement in the httpd parser, though.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and didnt parse. I will have to grok this thing up I suppose.